# add a filter with urlMapping on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a class like this

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/message/*","/private_message"})
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends FilterRegistrationBean {
```

and I thought that Spring Boot would respect the urlPatterns setted, but for some reason, every request gets to this filter. I think I may be doing something wrong.
Also, I'm not using Spring Security

Comment: Why do you think spring would parse `@WebFilter`?

Comment: I don't know, I read somewhere on the stackoverflow, someone was using this

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It does in 1.3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#support-for-webservlet-webfilter-and-weblistener. That said, the usage in the question is wrong.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson how wrong? I just saw I'm not using `@ServletComponentScan`. can that be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing use of `@WebFilter` and `FilterRegistrationBean`. The former should be used on a class that is a `Filter` and in conjunction with `@ServletComponentScan`. The latter should be published as a bean (as you are doing by annotating with `@Component`) and the url mappings configured using its `setUrlPatterns` method.

Comment: How did you fix this ? I'm implementing Filter and tagged ServletComponentScan but still not working for me.